# Problem with project dependencies and logs in scala

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, maven, logging, log4j

I have two scala maven projects, we will call them "A" and "B".

"A" project is a dependency  of "B". I use "A" like a library; "A" is included in dependencies in "B" pom.xml file.
And I use `org.apache.logging.log4j.scala.Logging` library to see the logs with configuration files (xml extension) like this in the *src/main/resources* folder in the both projects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} %L - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="group.id.projectname" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

When I run my tests I see perfectly the result of the logs in my IDE console.

But, when I run my project in a cluster in AWS I can see error and warn logs of the project "B" only.

In project "B":

- logger.error("message") -> yes
- logger.warn("message") -> yes
- logger.info("message") -> no
- logger.trace("message") -> no

In project "A": I can see all in IDE but nothing in a cluster

I have tried some things:

Remove:

```
<Logger name="group.id.projectA" level="trace" additivity="false">
 <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
</Logger>
```

Add dependency exclusion in pom file :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>group.id</groupId>
   <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
   <version>${projectB.version}</version>
   <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
       <artifactId>log4j-api-scala_${scala.tools.version}</artifactId>
       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
     </exclusion>
     <exclusion>
       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
     <exclusion>
       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
 </dependency>
```

- Change additivity="false" to additivity="true" in log4j2.xml file in "B" project
- Change additivity="false" to additivity="true" in log4j2.xml file in "B" project and "A" project

But no test has worked.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What do you mean by "run my project in a cluster"? Are you talking about something like EMR? I ask because normally, when you can't see logs, it's because there's another configuration file that's overriding what you specify.

Comment: Yes @kdgregory, when I run it in EMR.
I have two configuration files, one for each project, but I do not know how to make them not overwrite.

Comment: JVM chooses only one file. Log4j/logback ask for it. Probably the last one from dependencies. On JVM you has only binaries - the JVM do not distinguish between your classes and third part classes.